# extract value from a list after the occurrence of a number after certain time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a list like this, where there are some duplicate entries in groups of length-3 or more:

```
[1,2,1,1,1,2,3,4,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,1,3,5,2,2,6,4,1,6,1,1,3,5,2,2,6,4,1,6,2,7,2,6,1,1]

                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I want to extract the values from a particular point where there is no continuous occurrence of any number for 3 times from that point.

The extract to the point with the condition is same like above. And the list will always start with 1,3 or 4

I am looking for faster solutions than using a loop.

The expected output is the list:

```
[1,2,4,1,3,5,2,2,6,4,1,6,1,1,3,5,2,2,6,4,1,6,2,7,2,6,1,1]
```

Comment: Why isn't the result [1,2,2,3,4...]

Comment: @SteveJ because there is nothing like that in the list

Comment: If I remove the three continuous '1's from the starting list, that is what I have left.

Comment: Why not [1,2,3,4,1,2,5,1,1...]? Seems to me the first occurrence of 3 no continuous numbers

Comment: Stackoverflow and users are here to guide you, not do the work for you. Please present an attempted solution before asking for someone to look into why you aren't getting an expected result, otherwise don't use Stackoverflow.

Comment: They want to find the index of the last group of at least three consecutive values, then slice everything after that index. In this case it's 16, so they want `l[16:]`

Comment: @Valentino because there is 1 more than three times after that

Comment: @Paulie I did it using the loop. I want to avoid it as it takes long time to execute.

Comment: Then post your solution and ask how to improve it's performance or are there any other solutions to achieve this which can be suggested.

Comment: I think a lack of attempt doesn't warrant 10 downvotes.  This is a valid question.  Sure, OP can take some advice and improve the question but there was no need to downvote into oblivion.

Comment: All: I highlighted the expected output, in the input list. Now so much clearer. (OP - next time everyone is confused at a question and it's raining downvotes, please edit it yourself to improve clarity. People are trying to help)

Comment: *"And the list will always start with 1,3 or 4"* : which, your input list, the sublist(s) of duplicates, or your expected output list? (If the former two, that's irrelevant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use `np.roll` to find the last index of three consecutive values.

```
import numpy as np

idx = ((l == np.roll(l, 1)) & (l == np.roll(l, 2))).cumsum().argmax()

l[idx:]
#[1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 1, 6, 2, 7, 2, 6, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Interestingly, I think OP should have included one more `1` in the expected results.  As the sequence `[1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, ...` also satisfies the requirements.

Comment: Yes that's a good point. EIther that, or none of the 1s seems more logical.